# Is there a setting or permissions the organizer (your boss) have to give to the assistant for the organizer to see the new attendee?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

If you are an assistant and have access to your boss calendar. You add a person from the organizer's calendar, but the organizer can't see the changes.  Is there a setting or permissions the organizer have to give to the assistant for the organizer to see the new attendee?

Answer (score 0):

> > but the organizer can't see the changes.

How did the organizer check the changes? By directly opening the meeting or other ways from the organizer's Outlook? According to my tests, when delegate changes the meeting from the organizer's calendar, it will be automaically synced to the organizer's calendar, there is no specific settings or permissions about this.